# Unit Testing Issue - Dialog box not rendering during unit test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, primevue

I have a page (parent component) that has a button and when clicked, it brings up a primevue dialog. The code of the button and dialog are in a child component. By default the dialog is not visible. When I do a unit test, how can I render the dialog to appear? console.log(wrapper) just shows the button. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
describe('DialogBoxForm.vue', () => {
let wrapper: VueWrapper;
beforeEach(async () => {

wrapper = mount(DialogBoxForm, {
global: {
stubs: { teleport: true, Toast: false },
plugins: [pinia, PrimeVue]
}
});
  await flushPromises();
});
console.log(wrapper)
```